# annotation / Metadata in dart lang

Tags: java, annotations, dart, metadata

Can anyone help to convert the below JAVA into DART...

I'm trying to understand the annotation, could not find enough documentations in DART, and found this JAVA example [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-custom-annotations-example/); tried to convert it into DART but failed :(

Test.java

```java
  package com.mkyong.test.core; 
  import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
  import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
  import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
  import java.lang.annotation.Target;

  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
  @Target(ElementType.METHOD) //can use in method only.
  public @interface Test {

      //should ignore this test?
      public boolean enabled() default true;
  }
```

TesterInfo.java

```java
package com.mkyong.test.core;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE) //on class level
public @interface TesterInfo {

 public enum Priority {
   LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH
}

Priority priority() default Priority.MEDIUM;

String[] tags() default "";

    String createdBy() default "Mkyong";
   String lastModified() default "03/01/2014";

 }
```

TestExample.java

```java
package com.mkyong.test;

import com.mkyong.test.core.Test;
import com.mkyong.test.core.TesterInfo;
import com.mkyong.test.core.TesterInfo.Priority;

@TesterInfo(
 priority = Priority.HIGH, 
 createdBy = "mkyong.com",  
 tags = {"sales","test" }
 )
 public class TestExample {

@Test
void testA() {
  if (true)
    throw new RuntimeException("This test always failed");
}

@Test(enabled = false)
void testB() {
  if (false)
    throw new RuntimeException("This test always passed");
}

@Test(enabled = true)
void testC() {
  if (10 > 1) {
    // do nothing, this test always passed.
  }
}

}
```

RunTest.java

```java
package com.mkyong.test;

 import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
 import java.lang.reflect.Method;

  import com.mkyong.test.core.Test;
  import com.mkyong.test.core.TesterInfo;

  public class RunTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  System.out.println("Testing...");

  int passed = 0, failed = 0, count = 0, ignore = 0;

   Class<TestExample> obj = TestExample.class;

   // Process @TesterInfo
   if (obj.isAnnotationPresent(TesterInfo.class)) {

    Annotation annotation = obj.getAnnotation(TesterInfo.class);
    TesterInfo testerInfo = (TesterInfo) annotation;

    System.out.printf("%nPriority :%s", testerInfo.priority());
    System.out.printf("%nCreatedBy :%s", testerInfo.createdBy());
    System.out.printf("%nTags :");

    int tagLength = testerInfo.tags().length;
    for (String tag : testerInfo.tags()) {
        if (tagLength > 1) {
            System.out.print(tag + ", ");
        } else {
            System.out.print(tag);
        }
        tagLength--;
    }

    System.out.printf("%nLastModified :%s%n%n", testerInfo.lastModified());

    }

    // Process @Test
    for (Method method : obj.getDeclaredMethods()) {

    // if method is annotated with @Test
    if (method.isAnnotationPresent(Test.class)) {

        Annotation annotation = method.getAnnotation(Test.class);
        Test test = (Test) annotation;

        // if enabled = true (default)
        if (test.enabled()) {

          try {
            method.invoke(obj.newInstance());
            System.out.printf("%s - Test '%s' - passed %n", ++count, method.getName());
            passed++;
          } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.out.printf("%s - Test '%s' - failed: %s %n", ++count, method.getName(), ex.getCause());
            failed++;
          }

        } else {
            System.out.printf("%s - Test '%s' - ignored%n", ++count, method.getName());
            ignore++;
        }

    }

   }
    System.out.printf("%nResult : Total : %d, Passed: %d, Failed %d, Ignore %d%n", count, passed, failed, ignore);

    }
 }
```

the output of the above should be:

> Testing...
>
> Priority :HIGH
>   CreatedBy :mkyong.com
>   Tags :sales, test
>   LastModified :03/01/2014
>
> 1 - Test 'testA' - failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: This test always failed 
>   2 - Test 'testC' - passed 
>   3 - Test 'testB' - ignored
>
> Result : Total : 3, Passed: 1, Failed 1, Ignore 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't take a close look at the code and what it does but the annotations

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD) //can use in method only.
```

have no equivalent in Dart. In dart every constant value can be applied as annotation at every place where annotations are allowed.

Some questions/answers about using annotations in Dart

- [dart, how to define a class so it can be used as a class attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26607247)
- [How retrive function that marks with metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26603981)
- [Getting ClassMirror instances for all classes that have an annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24457283)
- [Refer classes by their metadata tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111378)
- [How to retrieve annotations on declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23904314)
- [Dart meta programming features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23759041)
- [How to retrieve metadata in Dartlang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19492607)
- [How do I access metadata annotations from a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255368)

check out the tag `dart-mirrors` for more.

Information about writing unit tests in Dart https://www.dartlang.org/articles/dart-unit-tests/